# Split CSV data in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to create cross validation function. i have csv file that contain data:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
0.1,y,1,n
0.4,n,1,n
0.3,y,2,n
0.6,y,1,y
```

I open csv data in python and i want to split data become 2 data, so the result like this.

```
c1,c2,c3
0.1,y,1
0.6,y,1
```

and

```
c1,c2,c3
0.4,n,1
0.3,y,2
```

what function in csv modules can do that?

[EDIT]

my code :

```
def split(path_to_file):
    reader = csv.reader(file(path_to_file))
    split_1=[]
    split_2=[]
    for line in reader:
        split_1.append(line[:-1])
        split_2.append(line[:-1])

    print split_1
    print split_2
```

Problem :

```
split_1.append(line[:-1])
```

that code will return data exclude c4, but it show all data.

```
[[c1,c2,c3],[0.1,y,1],[0.4,n,1],[0.3,y,2],[0.6,y,1]]
```

How i split it?

Comment: How do you decide what data goes where?

Comment: @Altoyr  i edit the question, include my code.

Comment: The key question is, like @DirkHorsten already asked, how do you *want* to split the data? Currently, you have just read the data from the csv file and stored it in two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the a cross_validation function from the scikit-learn module like this:

```
import sklearn

c1_train, c1_test, c2_train, c2_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(c1, c2, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
c3_train, c3_test, c4_train, c4_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(c3, c4, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
```

If you want a 50-50 split with your code you can do this update:

```
import csv

def split(path_to_file):
  reader = csv.reader(file(path_to_file))

  split_1 = []
  split_2 = []
  i = 0
  for line in reader:
    if i == 0:
        split_1.append(line[:-1])
        split_2.append(line[:-1])
    elif  i % 2 == 0:
      split_1.append(line[:-1])
    else:
      split_2.append(line[:-1])       
    i = i + 1

  print split_1
  print split_2
```

Comment: thank you. But i'm not allowed to using sklearn module or else.